# How get the size or the image from DrawableLeft in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, custom-view

I am doing a floating hint to editText, but to make it perfect I need to know how is the size from image used in drawable left and I would like to know if is possible to get the attribute set from the original editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it is written

```
public void setCompoundDrawables(@Nullable Drawable left, @Nullable Drawable top,
            @Nullable Drawable right, @Nullable Drawable bottom)
```

if left, try this

```
int width = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[0].getMinimumWidth();
int height = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[0].getMinimumHeight();
```

Comment: Man I would like to animate the CompoundDrawables with fade in and fade out, do you know how I can do that ?

Comment: But I want to use just one drawable (I just have one rsrsrsrsrs).

Comment: so what's the problem? Use one

Comment: But how the animation will happen with just one image in animation-list ?